# MFC VS2010 Dialog Box Won't Get Smaller

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog

I am editing a GUI with Visual Studio 2010. In the resource view I have sized the GUI as in the picture below.

[image]

However when I run the program this is what it looks like.

[image]

As you can see the dialog box is bigger than what it's supposed to be. Does anyone know what could be causing this and how to fix it? As some additional information this is the .rc code for the dialog box. Also this is the main application window, not a popup.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any code that resizes the dialog box?

Comment: Not that I can find, what would the function be called that resizes it?

Comment: Look for an OnSize () event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Turns out there was a routine called `OnGetMaxMinInfo`. After changing the values the window sized according to those values.

```
void GEVPlayerDlg::OnGetMinMaxInfo( MINMAXINFO *lpMMI )
{
    lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = 480; //was 800
    lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = 460; //was 517
}
```